# HTML/CSS 4 Links/buttons

Tags: html, css, button, layout, hyperlink

I am trying to make 4 separate buttons in a layout in a foursquare type layout. (see attached image and pretend the boxes are the same size and equidistant from eachother) my issue is that i want the boxes to be in the center of the page no matter the browser window size, except i do not want the buttons to re-size when the page gets too small. I am drawing blanks at how to do this but it doesnt seem to hard.

[image: site layout]

```css
body{
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
 font-size:1em;
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
}

#content{
 position:relative;
}


/* Banner Styling */
#banner {
 display:inline-block;

}

#banner a{
 text-decoration:none;
 color:black;
}

#banner h1{
 float:left;
 padding-left:1em;
 padding-right:auto;
}

#banner #logo{
 position:absolute;
 top:0px;
 right:0px;
}

/* Navigation Styling */
Nav {
 margin-top:2em;
}

Nav ul{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 overflow:hidden;
 list-style-type:none;
 background-color: #1666af;
 padding-left:2em;
 min-width:1532px;
}

Nav ul li{
 float:left;
 text-align:center;
 
}

Nav li a{
 border: 1px solid #1666af;
 padding:.3em 2em .3em 2em;
 display: block;
 background-color: #1666af;
 color:White;
 text-decoration:none;
}

Nav .current{
 background-color:green;
 border:1px solid green;
}

Nav li a:hover{
 border: 1px solid #278efc;
 background-color:#278efc;
}

/* BUTTONS */
#buttons{
 position:relative;
 left:50%;
}
#buttons a{
 width:330px;
 height:210px;
 display:inline-block;
 text-align:center;
 color:white;
 text-decoration:none;
 border-radius:6px;
 margin-top:50px;
 box-sizing:border-box;
 padding-top:89px;
}

/* CDW Button */
#button1{
 border:1px solid black;
 background-color:green;
 transition: background-color 1.0s;
}

#button1:hover{
 background-color:yellow;
}

/* ADR button */
#button2{
 border:1px solid black;
 background-color:blue;
 transition: background-color 1.0s;
}

#button2:hover{
 background-color:red;
}

/* GoGatway Button */
#button3{
 border:1px solid black;
 background-color:red;
 transition: background-color 1.0s;
 height:60px!important;
 padding-top:20px!important;
}

#button3:hover{
 background-color:teal;
}

/* AAS button */
#button4{
 border:1px solid black;
 background-color:orange;
 transition: background-color 1.0s;
 height:60px!important;
 padding-top:20px!important;
}

#button4:hover{
 background-color:brown;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <title>Website</title>
 </head>

 <body>
 <div id="content">
  <div id="banner">
  <h1><a href="default.htm">Website</a></h1>
   <img id="logo" src="images/imagehere" alt="imagehere" />
  </div>
  <nav>
   <ul>
    <li><a class="current" href="default.htm"> Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="Placeholder.htm">Placeholder</a></li>
    <li><a href="Placeholder.htm">Placeholder</a></li>
    <li><a href="Placeholder.htm">Placeholder</a></li>
    <li><a href="Placeholder.htm">Placeholder</a></li>
    <li><a href="Placeholder.htm">Placeholder</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
  
  <div id=buttons>
   <a href="button1.htm" id="button1">Placeholder</a>
   <a href="button2.htm" id="button2">Placeholder</a>
   <a href="button3.htm" id="button3">Placeholder</a>
   <a href="button4.htm" id="button4">Placeholder</a>
  </div>
  
 </div>
 

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Fix your question, please. You can't link to a JSFiddle without code. Don't try to cheat to get around it, there's a reason it stopped you from doing it normally. Please read the question guidelines before posting.

Comment: Sorry about that, I didnt really understand what the site was prompting me to do. Someone was kind enough to edit it for me, I couldnt even figure out where the edit link was without ctrl-f lol

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id=buttons>
    <!--create a div here-->
    <div class="container" style=" width:100%, height:540px">

        <!--inside this div you create a new div for your foursquares-->
        <div class="forsquare">

            <!--use something like canvas to create the graphic or 
            use something like canvas to get the image how you would like it 
            you can also create a image and map it to create different a href 
            elements that links from the square-->
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: I would propose getting to work with something like bootstrap.

Comment: For cavas would i have to use JS to create the links and images then? I can do that but i was hoping to stay away from all that as it will probably have room for errors when others edit this site.

Edit: as well ive never used bootstrap before, Makes me a little nervous, I need to finish this up to be demo-able in the next week

Comment: Bootstrap is very easy everything is done with classes and data objects in your html code not alot of need to go into jquery.

Comment: alernatively try this in css  .forsquare {margin: 0  auto}   remember to set width to pixels for parent container. play around with that might get you the correct output